# how to fix beautifulsoup ssl CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED error

Tags: python-3.x, url, beautifulsoup, ssl-certificate, urlopen

#### Code:

```
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

html = urlopen("https://www.familyeducation.com/baby-names/browse-origin/surname/german")

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

metadata=soup.find_all('meta')
```

#### Error:

> urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED]

Comment: Please edit your question so that others can under it well to answer.

Answer (score 1):

For this error check out this answer:
[urllib and "SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED" Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27835619/urllib-and-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-error)

But you don't need `urlopen` for `html request` always. You can also send the request through `requests` lib. Try this one:

```
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = requests.get("https://www.familyeducation.com/baby-names/browse-origin/surname/german")

soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, "html.parser")

metadata = soup.find_all('meta')
```