# I am attempting to get BeautifulSoup to open wikipedia, but I'm getting a lot of errors back

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, pycharm

I am running bs4 on pycharm, and when I set up the code it is just throwing errors

```
import bs4
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = 'https://www.newegg.com/'

uClient = uReq(my_url)

page_html = uClient.read()

uClient.close()

page_soup = soup(page_html, 'html.parser')
```

> /Users/alirahman/PycharmProjects/scraper/venv/bin/python /Users/alirahman/PycharmProjects/scraper/app.py
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 1317, in do_open
>       encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1244, in request
>       self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1290, in _send_request
>       self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1239, in endheaders
>       self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1026, in _send_output
>       self.send(msg)
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 966, in send
>       self.connect()
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1414, in connect
>       server_hostname=server_hostname)
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 423, in wrap_socket
>       session=session
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 870, in _create
>       self.do_handshake()
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 1139, in do_handshake
>       self._sslobj.do_handshake()
>   ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1076)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/Users/alirahman/PycharmProjects/scraper/app.py", line 7, in 
>       uClient = uReq(my_url)
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 222, in urlopen
>       return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 525, in open
>       response = self._open(req, data)
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 543, in _open
>       '_open', req)
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 503, in _call_chain
>       result = func(*args)
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 1360, in https_open
>       context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 1319, in do_open
>       raise URLError(err)
>   urllib.error.URLError:
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [urllib and "SSL: CERTIFICATE\_VERIFY\_FAILED" Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27835619/urllib-and-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-error)

Comment: I voted to close, since the answer is elsewhere - note that a very similar question is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55096291/how-to-fix-beautifulsoup-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-error linking to the answer I ended using in the close vote

Answer (score 1):

Use `requests` library instead of `urllib.request`. The following should work.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = requests.get("https://www.newegg.com/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
```